# Responsive buttons in react js render

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, styles

I have a custon class inside my react js render , it's a style to make 3 buttons inline (2 on the right and one to the left) in the same line.

But the buttons are not responsive to mobile and other screens, I tried to put the style in a custom css stylesheet but it didn't work and the buttons didn't show up inline.

[Here is my CodeSandBox.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/reactjs-declarative-example-n4stf)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with the property `flex-wrap: wrap` on `parentStyle`. This will make the prev and next buttons move to the next line as you resize. Similarly you can use the same property in this line `<div style={{ ...childStyle, justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>` as well to move the next button below the prev button if the browser is resized further

Comment: This only move retun buttons on top of next button, but return to main button still the same, can you try on codesandbox please ?

Comment: Well, I had to change a lot of lines to get the desired result. Please checkout the forked codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-declarative-example-pdw65

Comment: Sorry. can you check now?

Comment: It's working thanks , is there a way to  put next first then return then return to main page when resizing ? (the opposite of the exisitng)

Comment: Yes. For that you need to set `flexWrap` to `wrap-reverse`. Try this on both the styles. But, please verify on all the browsers `wrap-reverse` and `space-between` works correctly

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this, I want to put each button in new line in this case  :

[Small screen test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrQ2S.png)

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about a device that is 160px wide - iPhone 5 which has a small screen by today's standards  is 320px wide

Comment: Is there a solution with code that I can try ? @JonathanIrwin

Comment: There is no problem with your code, no one will open your site with 160px width wide ! , as @JonathanIrwin mentioned, minimum width is 320px and your code is working fine there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

They seem to line up - what is the problem?

Comment: check my reply with a screenshot